# Why big O for this equation is n cube?

Tags: data-structures

I have this question about why the big O for this equation is n cube ?

```
else if(key == 'x')
   C = matrixMult(A, B);
```

Thanks very much

Comment: Because matrix multiplication can be done O(n³) time (and actually faster than that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resulting matrix has n^2 entries. The computation of each entry can be done by a sum of n products, yielding n^3.

This is only valid for the textbook algorithm, as there exist faster algorithms, e.g. [Strassen's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) or [the fastest known algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm).